# RecyclerView items reset when scrolling down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` with expandable list items. The problem is that when I expand an item and scroll the items off-screen gets reset like this:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this and preserve the item's state?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be you have an error in the adapter. Can you post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the object in your ListAdapter to store the expansion state.  It may be that you need to create a new class that wraps the existing data and adds a boolean indicating if the row is expanded.  Then, when you re-initialize the view as the list is scrolled, you can set the view to be expanded or collapsed according to the data in the adapter.  The view itself can't hold this state for you because the view object is "recycled" to display a different record as the user scrolls.